# Why does my JSoup request return an empty document?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, screen-scraping, user-agent

I want to scrape the contents of a website but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "https://www.rl-trades.com";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36").get();
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

All I get is this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

The problem seems to be the website because every similar question asked on here with a different website turned out to work for me. I also tried this more advanced version, but I get the exact same result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "https://www.rl-trades.com";
        Response response= Jsoup.connect(url)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")   
                .timeout(12000) 
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();

        Document doc = response.parse();

        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

Is there any way to still get the contents? Or is there just a scraping protection on the site with no work-around?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this website likes an Accept-Language header:

```
String url = "https://www.rl-trades.com";
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
connection.header("Accept-Language","en");
Document doc = connection.get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Really appreciate it!